# How can I log the result of a function that returns a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to log a function that returns the result of a function as so:

```js
    function rutRow(x){
      return function(){
        return x;
      }
    }
    
    console.log(rutRow(4));  // expect 4, getting function(){ return x; }
```

Comment: `console.log(rutRow(4)());` <-- execute the function it returns

Comment: well, to answer your syntactically asked question: `console.log(rutRow(4).toString())`

Comment: Well, `rutRow` returns a function. Not sure why you expect it to return 4.

Comment: @Casey, I've added an answer for you. Is that helped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is call **currying**. When you call `rutRow(4)` it retuns **another function** not **value**. Let's do it with adding an extra parenthesis `()` for your case to get the expected data **4**

**Currying** *Named after Haskell Brooks Curry, currying is the process of breaking down a function into a series of functions that each take a single argument.*

**It works like this way,**

> It accepts one argument and returns one function. The returned
>   function also accepts one argument and also returns another function
>   that also accepts one argument and …

```js
function rutRow(x) {
  return function() {
    return x;
  }
}

console.log(rutRow(4)());
```

**See more:** https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e